# Reading a file's contents after fetching

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch

After importing the files with appropriate header names, I am trying to read the contents with .text() method. The methods should return a promise with the resolved data. How come I am still getting "undefined" when I console.log(text)?

```
//fetch the three forms
let headerArr = ['text/html', "text/plain", "application/json","application/rainbows+unicorns"]

for (let type of headerArr){

  fetch("https://eloquentjavascript.net/author" , {headers: {'Accept': type}})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.headers.get("Content-Type"));
      console.log(response.status);
      response.text();
      })
    .then(text=> console.log(text));

}
```

Below is the alternative way of doing it from the book Eloquent JavaScript. Instead, they used the async method instead of then/catch. They get the desired result. How come this is the case?

```
const url = "https://eloquentjavascript.net/author";
const types = ["text/plain",
               "text/html",
               "application/json",
               "application/rainbows+unicorns"];

async function showTypes() {
  for (let type of types) {
    let resp = await fetch(url, {headers: {accept: type}});
    console.log(`${type}: ${await resp.text()}\n`);
  }
}

showTypes();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first block, you need to return `response.text()`:

```
return response.text()
```

`response.text()` returns a promise. If the result of a callback to `then()` is a promise, then the next `then()` in the chain will be called with the resolved value of that new promise.

Right now your first then handler returns nothing (`undefined`), so that value will also be passed to the next promise in the chain.